# How to setup a Xiaomi Mi Band without an internet connection?

Tags: xiaomi

I have a phone with no internet connection and I want to pair it with a Xiaomi Mi Band.

Is there any way to do that since the Xiaomi app asks for online registration? Or at least, can I use the internet just for the activation and then keep using it offline normally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must login to your Mi account before pairing Mi Band for the first time. Thereafter you only need Bluetooth connection.

Yes you can use Xiaomi Mi Band offline. It asks for connection only for login. After login it will never ask for internet connection.

Xiaomi Mi Fit App provides for syncing data with Google Fit, WeChat, Facebook and many others. But all that sharing requires internet connection.

I have used MiBand in offline mode for 10 months.

Answer (score 0):

After you connect to your Mi Account (with internet) and connect your band, it will work fine for 1 month.

After that, it is not possible to use the band without connecting to the Mi Account again.